# Unable to use Console.Log() within a WebBrowser Control

Tags: javascript, c#

So I'm writing a Javascript coding UI using C# Windows Forms. This is my code for when the "Run" button is pressed, in case it helps:

```cs
//If the button in the upper-right corner is clicked
    private void run_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //If the program isn't running
        if (!running)
        {
            //Show the web browser
            webBrowser1.Visible = true;
            richTextBox1.Visible = false;
            //Set the label to Running
            status.Text = "Running";
            //Set the html text to this below
            webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><script>\n" + richTextBox1.Text + "\n</script></body></html>";
            //Set the "run" button to "stop"
            run.Text = "Stop";
            //Set the status to running
            running = true;
        }
        //otherwise
        else
        {
            //Show the text box
            webBrowser1.Visible = false;
            richTextBox1.Visible = true;
            //Set the label to Ready
            status.Text = "Ready";
            //Go to nothingness
            webBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank");
            //Set the "stop" button to "run"
            run.Text = "Run";
            //Set the status to not running
            running = false;
        }
    }
```

I run the program, and for the most part, everything works fine. However, when I try to use the console.log() command, the following error appears:

```
'console' is undefined
```

I also try Console.Log (I actually don't know Javascript; just trying my best) but that returns the same error, that 'Console' is undefined.

Also, once I get console.log working, how do I open the console on the WebBrowser control? I've tried searching the internet, but nothing has come up on either of these questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, Console class is not available in your browser control, but you can create a logger class like this

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public class Logger
{
    public void log(string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

and use it in your browser control

```
webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = new Logger();
webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<script>external.log('TEST');</script>";
```

Answer (score 11):

You **can** get JavaScript console output from within Visual Studio.

By default the webBrowser1 control uses IE7 to render it's output.  IE7 does not have a console.log() function.  In order to get the console.log() function to work, you need to add the following meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11">
```

'IE=8' or greater should make the console.log() available to you.

When you debug a Windows Forms application it debugs using the .NET Managed Code debugger.  In order to debug differently, instead of pressing 'Play' to debug, try selecting "Debug" > "Start without Debugging".  Now once your application is running, go to "Debug" > "Attach to Process" and find your WindowsFormsApplication.exe, attach to it *using the Script Code Debugger instead of the .NET Managed Code debugger*.

Now, in Visual Studio:

- You can open "Debug" > "Windows" > "JavaScript Console"
- You can also open "Debug" > "Windows" > "DOM Explorer"

Comment: How would you ever "discover" these steps..[mind boggles]...It worked anyway - thank you!